# Encrypting InMemoryAuthentication passwords with Bcrypt

Tags: spring, spring-security

Before I use Bcrypt on a custom implementation of UserDetailsService, I first want to see if I can use it in an in-memory database.

```
package com.patrick.Security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/shifts").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "SUPERVISOR")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

With creating/exposing the PasswordEncoder bean this warning pops up which ultimately prevents me from accessing the login path:

```
o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
```

Adding the Deprecated NoOpPasswordEncoder will temporarily solve the issue, but obviously wont encode the passwords:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Bean
public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
}
```

What's the correct way to add Bcrypt?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> With creating/exposing the PasswordEncoder bean this warning pops up
>   which ultimately prevents me from accessing the login path:

```
o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt
```

This is because the password you're providing is not encoded with BCrypt. Instead of passing `"password"` directly as the password it needs to be encoded first.

For testing purposes, an easy way of doing this would be to just get a hold of your password encoder and encode it in your configure method like this

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    String password = passwordEncoder().encode("password");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password(password).roles("ADMIN");
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Comment: Ah yes. Seems obvious now. I was under the impression that it was done automatically.

Answer (score 4):

With [Spring Security 5](https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released#password-storage-format) you can prefix password with `id` of selected `PasswordEncoder`. If you want to use plain password, then simply use `{noop}` prefix, this will delegate password encoder to `NoOpPasswordEncoder`.

Example code:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
   auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("admin").password("{noop}password").roles("ADMIN");
}
```

Comment: With Spring Boot 5.1, this solution causes performance hit (> 100ms each time the password is checked), because for some reason BCryptPasswordEncoder is initialized. Hopefully it will be fixed later.